# Replace date from url

Tags: javascript

I would like  to write a javascript function that replace a date in the format YYYY/MM/DD from an url to a specific string.

```
var url = "http://localhost/reussitemlm/2015/09/08/comment-vous-eviter-de-perdre-votre-attractivite-aux-yeux-de-vos-prospects/";

var newUrl = replaceDate(url, 'qtvideo');

console.log(newUrl);
"http://localhost/reussitemlm/qtvideo/comment-vous-eviter-de-perdre-votre-attractivite-aux-yeux-de-vos-prospects/"
```

Comment: seems like a basic regular expression, what did you try?

Comment: Can you show us what you’ve tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use a RegEx(`d` for digit) that searches for the expression `dddd/dd/dd`

```js
let url = "http://localhost/reussitemlm/2015/09/08/comment-vous-eviter-de-perdre-votre-attractivite-aux-yeux-de-vos-prospects/",
date_format = /\d{4}\/\d{2}\/\d{2}/;

url = url.replace(date_format, "qtvideo");
console.log(url);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is rather rudimentary and I'm sure that regex experts have better patterns but the following expression should match

```
/[0-9]{4}\/[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{2}/
```

Use it like this

```
var url = "http://localhost/reussitemlm/2015/09/08/comment-vous-eviter-de-perdre-votre-attractivite-aux-yeux-de-vos-prospects/";

url.replace(/[0-9]{4}\/[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{2}/, 'qtvideo');
```

Answer (score -1):

```
function replaceDate(url,str){
       let regex = /\d{4}[\/.]\d{1,2}[\/.]\d{1,2}/;
       let res = url.replace(regex.exec(url)[0], str);
       return res;

}
```

This should work for you ... thanks

Comment: If you're going to add contingencies that the author hasn't specified you should say why.

Comment: Actually this is my first answer.  So please pardon me if I have not done it properly...